ASP.NET MVC TempData does not clear
I'm a bit confused. I thought when using TempData that the object is supposed to be cleared if it's read. I'm not entirely sure why I have to call the Remove() function directly when I am doing a RedirectToAction when I believe (at least) I'm clearing reading the TempData.
Here is the code I'm using, and any help, is of course helpful. If this is the behavior, I might as well use Session.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgetPassword(Models.Portal.ForgetPasswordModel forgetPasswordModel)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           int forgetAttemptCounter = TempData[ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt] == null ? 1 : (int)TempData[ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt];
           int maxCounter = 5;

           if (forgetAttemptCounter <= maxCounter)
           {
               bool useEmail = Helper.Validation.IsValiEmailAddress(forgetPasswordModel.AccountName);

               if (forgetPasswordModel.ForgetPasswordReset == Models.Portal.ForgetPasswordReset.Success)
               {
                   TempData.Remove(ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt);
                   return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "Portal", new Models.Portal.ResetPasswordModel());
               }
               else
               {
                   TempData[ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt] = (int)TempData[ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt] + 1;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               TempData[ConstLibrary.ForgetPasswordAttempt] = maxCounter + 1;
               ViewBag.ShowForgetPasswordError = true;
               return View(forgetPasswordModel);
           }
       }

       ViewBag.ShowForgetPasswordError = true;

       return View(forgetPasswordModel);
}


Covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630678/tempdata-not-being-cleared  TempData is only cleared when a request results in a 200. Redirect responses won't clear the TempData, they are treated as a continuation of the request, so you need to clear it manually.

This question is similar to: TempData Not Being Cleared. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
